# How to get numbers from a string in a text file and sum them

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a program that reads info from a text file.

What i need to do is get the numbers from the text file and sum them upp for each individual who is in the textfile.

Comment: "This is my code, but its hardcoded, I need a loop or an array i suppose to store numbers." - You need both a loop and an array. Why not try it yourself and see?

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
while (line = br.readLine() != null) {
    String[] arr = line.split(";");
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (k > 2) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(arr[k]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

can u change the input format. like instead of

**surname;name;email;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7**

to

**surname;name;email;0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7**

i.e use a different delimiter for the numbers?? so , to just alter ur answer

```
String[] parts = line.split(";");
String numbers = parts[3].split("-");
Integer sum = 0;

for( int index=0; index < numbers .length; index++){
 sum+= Integer.parseInt(numbers[index]); 
}

System.out.println( parts[0] ) ; // Prints surname
System.out.println( sum ) ; //prints the sum for the current surname
```

or if you are stubborn about your format

```
String[] parts = line.split(";");
Integer sum =0;
for( int index =0; index < parts.length ; index++){
   try{
   sum += Integer.parseInt(parts[index]);
}
catch(Exception e){
  // parts[index] is not a number. Do whatever u want based on index value ( index ==0 means surname??
}
}
```